# Unable to execute PowerShell Script

Tags: windows, powershell

How can I get my PowerShell script to execute?

When I run my script I get the error:
`File cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system`

Can you help me to get my script to run?

```
set-executionpolicy unrestricted
#Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

$target=[IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\usermenuTest1.4d")
$output=[IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\usermenuTest2.4d")

($output -replace $target) | Set-Content "usermenuTest2.4d.new"

Start-Sleep -s 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx#EEAA) suggests trying `Get-ExecutionPolicy` to check your script execution policy, and then set it to `AllSigned` or `Unrestricted`. Also, make sure you run the script like this `".\scriptname.ps1"`

Comment: RemoteSigned is another widely used value for ExecutionPolicy.

Comment: `& powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file C:\script.ps1` to completely ignore the execution policy.

Comment: You can also use `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force` to temporarily get around it without changing system defaults